# Synchronization using svnkit

Tags: svn, diff, synchronize, svnkit

I would like to list all inbound and outbound changes of a project, that is, everything that is going to be commited as well as everything that is comming in the next update. A kind of "syncronize" that eclipse does.
In terms of svn, I'd like to reproduce this command:

```
svn diff -rHEAD --summarize
```

actually there is a command called doDiffStatus, which I tried to use this way(and some other variations):

```
SVNRevision localRevision = clientManager.getStatusClient().doStatus(folder, false).getRevision();
diffClient.doDiffStatus(folder, localRevision, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNRevision.UNDEFINED, SVNDepth.EMPTY, true, new ISVNDiffStatusHandler() {...})
```

but it always throws a NPF. Investigating the source code, it seems that I can't use a local copy to compare against a remote repository.

Is it possible to do so? I can achieve the same goal using just dodiff, but I don't want to parse a patch file...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution asking the remote status. Use doStatus and ask for getRemotePropertiesStatus() and getRemoteContentsStatus()